# Stream iPhone App screen to another iPhone using swift

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming

I want to create an app where one user creates something on his/her screen and other people can watch it. I'm still confused on how I can use swift to implement a function that allows my users to live stream to one another. I've googled ways to do this and I haven't had any success so far, I'm almost looking for something like periscope except you stream only the app screen.

Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task to accomplish and you will need to look into real-time backend services like PubNub. [They have a tutorial that will hopefully help point you in the right direction](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-ios-apps-getting-started-with-swift-and-pubnub/).

The next bit that you need to consider is how to capture the user's screen or a portion of it, which again is not entirely trivial. [Here is more information on screen video capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037443/iosswift-video-screen-capture).

The gist of it will be to capture the data, publish it to a real-time backend service, and then other users will "subscribe" to those data feeds to download and display the video capture.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know where to start. Yeah I figured it wouldn't be easy but I'm up for a challenge.