# Is there a way in iOS to record an animated drawing in a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, video, recording

I'm writing an iOS app in swift where I create drawings in a UIView using UIBezierPath's, and the drawings themselves are animated as they're created over a several-second period. I then allow the user to save their drawings. 
What I'm trying to figure out if whether it's possible to save the animation that occurs while the drawing is being created - and not just the final drawing. 
Would love any input.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037443/iosswift-video-screen-capture

Answer (score 4):

iOS 9 added ReplayKit, which makes it easy to record the screen in your app. You can also record your app's audio output and the microphone input.

[`RPScreenRecorder` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ReplayKit/Reference/RPScreenRecorder_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/RPScreenRecorder/startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:handler:)
[ReplayKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ReplayKit/Reference/ReplayKit_Collection/)